# Angular: how to modify a method of library

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select library (v9.x) (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select)
And now this library has an issue on all versions (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/pull/2134), but only have PR to fix this issue on the latest version (>10.x).

I want to extend the NgSelectComponent to override a method of this component (focus method) to fix that issue.

So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can fork the library form GitHub, do your fixes and then package the library, create a tar.gz and install it locally.

Comment: Do you mean clone code, fix it, and use it the same as a component.

Comment: yes, when you clone the code and edit it, you essentially created a fork

Comment: Thank you @Zerotwelve. Actually, I don't understand after editing the code in the fork branch and commit it. How can I use it in my project same as installing the new version  "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.x.x.fixversion", I will try to investigate more. If you have more details about the way to do that, please let me know.

Comment: Build the libary using the `ng build` command and then move the the build (or dist) directory and pack it with the `npm pack` command.
This should create a tar.gz that you can use for installation i.e. `npm install /path/to/my-lib.tar.gz`

Comment: thanks for your support, I tried an other way to fix this issue by use   @ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) ngSelectComponent: NgSelectComponent;
 and override method in ng-select component  this.ngSelectComponent['focus'] = () => {}